# Bootstrap3 execute Jquery function only when screen is below 480 width

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, conditional-statements, scrolltop

I am using Bootstrap 3 with accordions to display page content. I have a Jquery script that uses scrollTop to animate the panel heading to the top of the screen when a panel opens. The script works great but I can't figure out how to ONLY make it fire when the screen with is less than 480 width. I know I need to watch for a screen resize event as well.

```
$('#collapse-slide-line-tabs').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
var panel = $(this).find('.panel-collapse.in');

$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: panel.offset().top - 114
}, 200);return false;
});
```

Below is my latest non-working attempt.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#collapse-slide-line-tabs').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 480) {
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: panel.offset().top - 114
            }, 200);return false;
    }
});
});
```

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong?

--- UPDATE below --

Moving the window width condition outside of the function call seemed to solve my first problem.

```
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
$('#collapse-slide-line-tabs').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {

  var panel = $(this).find('.panel-collapse.in');

  $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: panel.offset().top - 114
  }, 200);return false;});

}
```

I am still struggling though to kill the function on window resize to a width greater than 480

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {

if ($(window).width() < 480) {
  $('#collapse-slide-line-tabs').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {

  var panel = $(this).find('.panel-collapse.in');

    $('body').animate({
          scrollTop: panel.offset().top - 114
    }, 500);return false;});

    } else {
    $('body').animate.stopPropagation();}

});
```

(note that I am using two different animate speeds to help identify which script is affecting the content as I test)

Comment: Doesn't `$(window).width() < 480` work? What's then the returned value opposed to the expected one?

Comment: You could use instead: `if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 479px)").matches)`, maybe a device issue  http://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia

Comment: Thanks A. Wolff, I got the if window.width to work by moving it outside of the function call. So that part is now working. the last bit I'm trying to fix, is the resize event. I can't figure out how to kill the function if the window is resized above 480. I'll post my updated script above

Comment: A. Wolff, if you post your comment as an answer I can choose it as correct.